# how to get header file in csv file in jmeter?

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I have created the script in GUI MODE and running the script in not GUI mode and it generates the CSV file but it is not adding header file in the CSV file. How to add it?

Answer (score 1):

just add -f in your code in GUI mode after moving to the bin folder
Here is the code:

jmeter -f -n -t"templates\Lucene_search1.jmx" -l "templates\Lucene_Search_Results_Data1.csv" -e -o"C:\Starting Python\apache-jmeter-5.0\HTML_Reports"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

Also be aware that if you're appending the results into the existing file - JMeter will not add field names to it, you will either need to delete the existing results file and re-run the test or redirect the output into a new file and copy header and the new results from the new file into the old file manually.

References:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)